# Save live streaming video to document directory

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

I am playing .m3u8 url, and want save this video stream to device document directory for offline viewving. i am not sure weather it is possible.

Comment: http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/69772-recording-streaming-video.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html

Comment: If using adaptive streaming, what do you want to be downloaded to the documents directory?
If the user seeks, do you still want to download the skipped part?

Answer (score 1):

You can download segments from m3u8 file something like that:

```
NSString * result = NULL;
NSError * error = nil;
NSURL * urlToRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:_streamURL];
if(urlToRequest) {
    result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: urlToRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
}
```

The result variable will store the m3u8 file contents.

To parse is into segments you can use the code below:

```
NSMutableArray * lines = [[result componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] mutableCopy];
for (NSString * line in lines) {
    if ([line rangeOfString:@"segment"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Segment: %@", line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An m3u8 file is a playlist. It provides HTTP links to the video segments. So what you're really asking is if it is possible to save an HTTP entity to the document directory.

Obviously, the answer is yes.

That said maybe you want to record what is being downloaded by the video player (which means if the user uses the seek bar, you're going to get weird results), or maybe you want to download the highest quality possible.

If you want to record what is being downloaded, the best way to do it is to put an http proxy into the application that saves the resources to file as well as sending them on to the requester.

Comment: thanks for the reply man. Currently what i m doing is playing m3u8 file directly with MPMoviePlayer. and i am not sure how can i download the segments using that m3u8 path.